Dimension of very general fiber of $f\colon S\to Y$ with $\dim Y<\dim S$ is positive
Say we have a fibration $f\colon S\to Y$ between normal projective varieties with $\dim Y<\dim S$. Is a very general fiber of this morphism of positive dimension ? I heard this was true but I don't understand why it would be. It should follow by some result like
this one but how can we be sure that $y$ is in $U$ ? From what I understand $y$ is in the complement of some countable union of closed subsets, what happens if $U$ is inside this union ?

@Shrugs A very general fiber is a fiber of a very general point, that is a point which is in the complement of a countable union of closed subvarieties. I take my deifnition from Lazarself. Are they the same ?

In your setup every fibre of $f$ has positive dimension. This follows for example from Theorem 7 in Section I.6.3 of Shafarevich Volume 1. This says: given a surjective map $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ between irreducible varieties (which I assume you include in your hypotheses), then
--- every component of every fibre $f^{-1}(y)$ has dimension at least $\dim X - \dim Y$;
--- there is a nonempty open subset $U \subset Y$ such that for $y \in U$ the fibre $f^{-1}(y)$ has dimension equal to $\dim X -\dim Y$.
The "very general" condition is not relevant here.
